# Is there a way to compute anomalies of temperature without using "groupby"?

Tags: python, group-by, data-anomalies

I have downloaded 20 years of temperature reanalysis data from CMEMS. They represent daily temperature in 141 levels, in Mediterranean, between 1993 and 2012. It is an xarray dataset with this characteristics
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR4wg.png)
I have also downloaded the climatology offered by CMEMS for the same period and same place. It is also an xarray with this characteristics
[climatology dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYel0.png)
Now I need to compute anomalies of temperature, which usually are data - climatology. Usually I use this code

```
ds_clm=ds_clm.rename({'time': 'month'})
ds_temp_ano = ds_temp.groupby('time.month') - ds_clm
```

The problem is that this code is not working and it is killing my kernel.

I have tried with

```
ds_clm_broadcasted = xr.broadcast(ds_clm.thetao_avg, ds_temp.thetao)[0]
```

where thetao is my temperature variable, but this is also killing my kernel. I have tried with a simple

```
ds_temp_ano = ds_temp.thetao - ds_temp_clm
```

but it is subtracting clm only to day 16 of each month only in the first year. I have no other ideas how to compute this.